# How is background-size percentage calculated?

Tags: css, background-size

I have a sprite that I am using and I wanted to reuse one of the images in the sprite but at half the size so I thought if I just used `background-size:50%;`, it would resize the background by 50%, but it seemed to quarter the size for some reason:

```css
.test {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaIav.png) left top no-repeat;
  width: 112px;
  height: 112px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.test.half-size {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  background-size: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test half-size"></div>
```

Now I can fix this by having the background size as 113%:

```css
.test {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaIav.png) left top no-repeat;
  width: 112px;
  height: 112px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.test.half-size {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  background-size: 113%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test half-size"></div>
```

But why is the `background-size` greater than 100% when the image is smaller than the original?

Is there a set calculation I can apply when figuring out how to resize the sprite?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [***W3C Specs***](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-size):

> A percentage is relative to the ***background positioning area***.

and [background positioning area](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#background-origin) is one of either `border-box` or `padding-box` or `content-box` based on the `background-origin` property. Here you haven't specified any value explicitly for this and so its default value of `padding-box` is used. This element has no padding and so it's equal to `content-box`.

---

Your image is 126 x 112 px but width and height of the element is 56 x 56px, so a `background-size: 100%` (which is inferred as`100% auto`) would mean the image is scaled down till it has a width of 56px. Now to get to `56px`, the width is scaled down by 44.44% of the image's original size. So, ***to preserve aspect ratio*** (as one value is auto), the ***height*** of the image is ***also scaled down*** to 44.44%, which is, 49.78px (or `50px` approximately). As you can see the calculated background image's dimensions are 56px x 50px (and not 56px x 56px) and so it doesn't cover the box entirely. You can see this clearly in the below snippet.

```css
.test {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaIav.png) left top no-repeat;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-size: 56px 50px; /* see how this is same as 100% or 100% auto */
}

.test.t2 {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.test.t3 {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test t2"></div>
<div class="test t3"></div>
```

***Note:*** The `56px` width includes the white-spaces on the right side of the circle and so even though it covers the entire width of the element, you will still see a gap. This is due to the image itself having a space.

---

Now when you set `background-size: 50%` ( = `50% auto`), it would mean the max width of the image can be `28px` and so it is scaled down by 22.22%. This means the height is also scaled down 22.22%, which is, roughly `25px`. This is why you see it as being ***almost*** quarter size (but not exactly quarter). This can again be seen visually in the below snippet:

```css
.test {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaIav.png) left top no-repeat;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-size: 28px 25px; /* again see how they are same */
}

.test.t2 {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  background-size: 50%;
}

.test.t3 {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  background-size: 50% auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test t2"></div>
<div class="test t3"></div>
```

---

When we set `background-size: 113%`, it means the the ***width can be max 113% of the container's width***, which would be, `63.28px` and this is roughly 50% of the original image's width. Since width is scaled down by `50%` from the original image, ***its height is also scaled down by same amount*** and so the resulting value is `56px` (which is nothing but the height of the element and so it covers the box vertically). Now, since you've also given the `background-position` as `left-top`, the image is placed with respect to the left edge of the container and so the white-space which is present on the right side of the image (the other `7.28px`) is invisible as the box will not show anything more than its width.

***You've already answered the second part of your question and so I'm not going over it again.***

---

**For Future Readers:** For OP's case, it might not be possible to get rid of the white-spaces because it is part of a sprite but if your case is different and you can get rid of the spaces then that is the best.

If the white-spaces on the right side are removed and the image is cropped to its actual size (which is, 112 x 112px) then just setting `background-size: 100% 100%` (or even `100% auto`) would be enough. The container element's dimensions when set as half or quarter (or whatever) size of the original will automatically do the scaling for us.

```css
.test {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaCct.png) left top no-repeat;
  width: 112px;
  height: 112px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.test.half-size {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
}

.test.quarter-size {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test half-size"></div>
<div class="test quarter-size"></div>
```

Comment: Nice explanation, now I get why it is as a ratio to the sprite rather than anything to do with the new box, thanks

Comment: You're welcome @Pete and you made it easier for me to answer because though I knew how it was done, it would have taken time for me to come up with the percentage for your second question.

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of playing around with the sprite I have come to the conclusion that it is width of full sprite divided by width of sprite part and times it by 100 will give you the x-axis background size percentage and then do the same with height for the y-axis background size.

So in my case to get the x percentage, it was

```
(         126px         /         112px        ) * 100 = 112.5% 
  Full width of sprite     width of sprite part
```

and to get the y percentage it was

```
(         112px         /         112px        ) * 100 = 100% 
 Full height of sprite     height of sprite part
```

This means that a `background-size: 112.5% 100%` will work for any square div with that sprite:

```css
.test {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaIav.png) left top no-repeat;
  width: 112px;
  height: 112px;
  background-size: 112.5% 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.test.half-size {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
}
.test.random-size {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test half-size"></div>
<div class="test random-size"></div>
```